# Can't change the wordpress site url

Tags: urls

I am trying to change the site url of this site, xn--bebji5b.com... Currently the homepage url is showing [https://www.מכרז.com/home-2/](https://www.%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%96.com/home-2/)...  I tried to change the url from wordpress dashboard settings as well as by modifying wp-config file. Also changed the static front page couple of time and changed hyperlink types. But nothing is working.

Comment: This happened after migrating it from another server.

Comment: After changing the `site url` from your WordPress dashboard, what do you get (see)?

Comment: Nothing. The same as now

Comment: If you don't want to do it in the admin panel, you can use a tool like SRDB (search and replace un the database). Don't forget to erase it After, it's very dangerous to leave it on a server...

Comment: I directly changed it on the server and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Login to your phpmyadmin and execute these mysql queries - change the value of url accordingly

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value,'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content,'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```